# BODY background image repeat or gradient for each TR into WebKIT browsers

Tags: html, css, html-table, webkit, gradient

My body background image repeat or gradient for each TR into WebKIT browsers.

*Is there any way this fix?*

My code: http://codepen.io/oskolsky/pen/ZYwzqE?editors=110

Сhromium Issue: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=35697

**What steps will reproduce the problem?**

1. Create a table with a tbody section
2. Add a background image or gradient using css to the table set to repeat-x 
   (horizontal)
3. Add several rows to the table body, enough to extend the table
   beyond the  height of the background image or gradient.

**What is the expected result?**

The table rows should show display a single image as their background.

**What happens instead?**

The background image is repeated for each table row.

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

tbody.special {
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(30,87,153,1) 0%, rgba(41,137,216,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%);
}

tr {

}

th, td {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>1</th>
      <th>2</th>
      <th>3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="special">
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>  
</table>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the exact question is here...could you clarify? It's a known Chrome bug.

Comment: Yes, it is a bug Chrome.

Comment: Maybe someone knows a hack or fix.

Comment: As reported in the Chromium bug track, it works on table. Posible workaround, then, is to apply another background to thead to mask it...

Comment: Mmm.. hadn't seen that you had 2 tbody ...   That will be difficult to hack. Is it really a must to have 2 tbodies ?

Comment: Yes, is required highlight the first three rows.

Comment: Run code snippet, please.